# center text and equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

how can I center the first equation `Max $Z = 0.15x_{1} + 0.12x_{2} + 0.1x_{3} + 0.05x_{4} + 0.08x_{5}$` and the text "s.a" with the other equations below ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel} % espanol
\decimalpoint
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
Luego el modelo matemático queda planteado como se muestra a continuación:\\

Max $Z = 0.15x_{1} + 0.12x_{2} + 0.1x_{3} + 0.05x_{4} + 0.08x_{5}$

s.a

\begin{equation}
 x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} \leq 1.000.000
\label{eqn:p1-r1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 x_{1} + x_{2} \leq 0.3(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5})
\label{eqn:p1-r2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 x_{4} \geq x_{5}
\label{eqn:p1-r3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 x_{3} + x_{4} \leq 0.5(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5})
\label{eqn:p1-r4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x_{4} \geq 0.25(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5})
\label{eqn:p1-r5}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item Resuelva el problema mediante el software de optimización OPL –CPLEX, y entregue la Solución y Valor
Optimo.\\
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega please add a compilable `MWE`. Though not THE way to typeset these type of equation. You can do it by using `display-math` style. Replace `$...$` by `\[...\]`.

Comment: I added compilable code right now! @Raaja I didn't get what you meant by "display-math"

Comment: since you're using `amsmath`, you might use the `gather` environment (with `\\ ` to separate lines) instead of entering each line as a separate `equation`.  and don't leave a blank line before any single or multi-line equation block.  the blank line will not prevent a page break (which is not desirable in such a location), and the use of a multi-line environment like `gather` will allow better control over page breaks between lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**: Not-so-correct way is to use `display-math` style as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel} % espanol
\decimalpoint
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Luego el modelo matemático queda planteado como se muestra a continuación:\\

 \[\max Z = 0.15x_{1} + 0.12x_{2} + 0.1x_{3} + 0.05x_{4} + 0.08x_{5}\]

s.a

\begin{equation}
 x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} \leq 1.000.000
\label{eqn:p1-r1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 x_{1} + x_{2} \leq 0.3(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5})
\label{eqn:p1-r2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 x_{4} \geq x_{5}
\label{eqn:p1-r3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 x_{3} + x_{4} \leq 0.5(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5})
\label{eqn:p1-r4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  x_{4} \geq 0.25(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5})
\label{eqn:p1-r5}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item Resuelva el problema mediante el software de optimización OPL –CPLEX, y entregue la Solución y Valor
Optimo.\\
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

with which you will get:

[image]

**Method 2**: The (IMO) current way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368570/typesetting-an-optimisation-problem
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{alignat}{2}
        &\!\max_{m(t)}        &\qquad& F(t)=m(t)a(t)^2\\
        &\text{s.a} &      &  E(t)=m(t)c(t)^2,\\
        &                  &      &  m(t)=\text{If I knew I would be the great E}
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: and how can I move "s.a" at the same horizontal position than "max Z" ?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question, what is that "&" operator for that you use inside of "alignat" ?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega It is mostly like a definition or a marker to define the alignment (to the best of my understanding) and you are welcome!